# Como puedo colocar un nombre a cada fila resultante de UNION en Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

La idea es que luego de hacer una UNION en SQL server
poder identificar con un nombre cada fila, para poder identificar de que tabla viene la data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo agrega un campo más a cada fila con el nombre de la tabla

```
    select dato1, dato2, 'nombre tabla' as nombreTabla from tabla1
    union all
    select dato1, dato2, 'nombre tabla 2' from tabla2
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer usando alias las columnas de resultados
Seguido la columna o tabla que consultas agregas la palabra reservada AS, o solo agregando un espacio 
Ejemplo

```
SELECT columna 1 AS nuevo nombre, columna 2   nuevo nombre o tabla AS nuevo nombre  FROM tabla          AS nuevo nombre
union all
SELECT  columna 1 AS nuevo nombre, columna 2  AS nuevo nombre FROM tabla2 AS nuevo nombre
```